# Does ToString() produce a new string on when used on strings?

Tags: c#, .net, string

Does `"hello".ToString()` produce a new string or is it smart enough to return a reference to the same object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer your question in the title: no.

According to .NET Reflector, calling `.ToString()` or `.ToString(IFormatProvider)` on a `string` it just returns itself.

Comment: Also according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tc6ws5s.aspx): "Returns this instance of String; no actual conversion is performed."

Comment: @NullUserException - thanks. I didn't know it was actually in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can test this hypothesis with a simple assertion:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

void ToStringHypothesis()
{
    string myString = "Hello!";
    string otherString = myString.ToString();

    Debug.Assert(Object.ReferenceEquals(myString, otherString));
}
```

Since strings are immutable in .NET, the sensical implementation of `String.ToString()` implementation is to return a reference to itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is smart enough (at least [in Mono](http://github.com/mono/mono/blob/mono-2.6.4/mcs/class/corlib/System/String.cs#L1845)):

```
public override String ToString ()
{
return this;
}
```